# Cannot conform to FBSDKSharingDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

I cannot conform my GameViewController to FBSDKSharingDelegate and I don't know why.

These are the function I think it need.

```
func sharer(sharer: FBSDKSharing, didCompleteWithResults results: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
}
func sharer(sharer: FBSDKSharing, didFailWithError error: NSErrorPointer) {
}
func sharerDidCancel(sharer: FBSDKSharing) {
    NSLog("share cancelled")
}
```

Am I missing something?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Solved.

```
func sharer(sharer: FBSDKSharing!, didCompleteWithResults results: [NSObject: AnyObject]) {
    print(results)
}

func sharer(sharer: FBSDKSharing!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    print("sharer NSError")
    print(error.description)
}

func sharerDidCancel(sharer: FBSDKSharing!) {
    print("sharerDidCancel")
}
```

Comment: i dont see any change in the question and answer

Comment: Just some "!" here and there

Answer (score 1):

The following solved my issue:

```
    public func sharerDidCancel(_ sharer: FBSDKSharing!) {

}


public func sharer(_ sharer: FBSDKSharing!, didFailWithError error: Swift.Error!) {

}

public func sharer(_ sharer: FBSDKSharing!, didCompleteWithResults results: [AnyHashable : Any]!) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my case for Swift 3

```
/*!
     @abstract Sent to the delegate when the sharer is cancelled.
     @param sharer The FBSDKSharing that completed.
     */
    public func sharerDidCancel(_ sharer: FBSDKSharing!) {

    }

    /*!
     @abstract Sent to the delegate when the sharer encounters an error.
     @param sharer The FBSDKSharing that completed.
     @param error The error.
     */
    public func sharer(_ sharer: FBSDKSharing!, didFailWithError error: Error!) {

    }

    /*!
     @abstract Sent to the delegate when the share completes without error or cancellation.
     @param sharer The FBSDKSharing that completed.
     @param results The results from the sharer.  This may be nil or empty.
     */
    public func sharer(_ sharer: FBSDKSharing!, didCompleteWithResults results: [AnyHashable : Any]!) {

    }
```